# PHP - Counting some values in column hieararchy

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i need help to calculate a value inside a hierarchy array. I have a table like this:

```
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
| kia_id |  kia_name  | value | parent_id |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
|      1 | ac service |       |         0 |
|      2 | hil        |       |         0 |
|      3 | dispatch   |       |         1 |
|      4 | tat main   | 13.3  |         3 |
|      5 | tat air    | 10.1  |         3 |
|      6 | sla comp   | 11.7  |         2 |
|      7 | sla serv   |       |         2 |
|      8 | slb        | 9.9   |         7 |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

i want to display to html that table like this :

```
+--------+----------------+-------+-----------+------------------------+
| kia_id |    kia_name    | value | parent_id | total_value_from_child |
+--------+----------------+-------+-----------+------------------------+
|      1 | ac service     |       |         0 | 23.4                   |
|      3 |    dispatch    |       |         1 | 23.4                   |
|      4 |       tat main | 13.3  |         3 |                        |
|      5 |       tat air  | 10.1  |         3 |                        |
|      2 | hil            |       |         0 | 21.6                   |
|      6 |    sla comp    | 11.7  |         2 |                        |
|      7 |    sla serv    |       |         2 | 9.9                    |
|      8 |       slb      | 9.9   |         7 |                        |
+--------+----------------+-------+-----------+------------------------+
```

how to count all child value to set the total of this parent, please help me..

Comment: I have removed incompatible tag pls. re-tag the `DBMS` that you are actually using.

Comment: @YogeshSharma okey, thank you ..

Comment: Is the total value for `ac_service` correct, and what happened to the value of `dispatch` in your expected result? The child of `ac_service` is `dispatch`, which has a value of `12.2` (in your original data). That has 2 further child `tat main` and `tat air`, with values of `13.3` and `10.1` respectively. `12.2 + 13.3 + 10.1 = 35.6` not `23.4`. Please explain your logic. Also post what you've already tried and provide your data in a consumable format: [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry, I've fixed it

Comment: Thanks, now you just need to post that consumable data and what your already tried. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to combine a recursive CTE with aggregation.  The idea is to start at the "bottom" (leafs) and work your way up.  Then aggregate to bring in the original data.

```
with cte as (
      select kia_id, value, kia_id as parent_id, 0 as lev
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.parent_id = t.kia_id)
      union all
      select cte.kia_id, cte.kia_value, t.parent_id, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join 
           t
           on cte.parent_id = t.kia_id
    )
select t.*, c.parent_value
from (select cte.parent_id, sum(kia_value) as parent_value
      from cte
      group by cte.parent_id
     ) c join
     t
     on t.kia_id = c.parent_id;
```